# Struggling with nesting golang html templates

Tags: go, templates

I'm still struggling with golang templates. I can get them to work. But not the way I need.

I would like to have a master `layout.gohtml` that then parses a page template `thispage.gohtml`. I want the master to be a complete layout with a `{{template "title" .}}`, `{{template "content" .}}`, etc. Then the page template will contain the changing content with `{{define ...}}` etc...

I can make this work if I parse the templates on every request and without FuncMaps. But I would like to parse them once and call them by name. This I cannot do. I just get a blank page with no errors. Been stuck on this for days.

I would also like to add some custom functions in FuncMaps for formatting etc. And this I cannot get to work in this nested scenario. It works for me in simpler non-nested scenarios.

Could someone please have a look at my code and tell me where I am going wrong? The output from this is just blank and debugging (in vscode) seems to reveal nothing obvious. Thanks...

This code produces a blank page and no errors... Expected output is a rendered page based on the templates... And tmpl.Execute with no name has the same blank result.

```
// Show handler
func Show(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    var page models.Page
    name := mux.Vars(r)["name"]

    switch r.Method {
    case "GET":

        if name != "" {
            page = models.GetPageByName(name)
        } else {
            page = models.GetPageByName("home")
        }

        data := make(map[string]interface{})
        data["Page"] = page

        funcMap := template.FuncMap{
            "toupper": strings.ToUpper,
        }

        var err error
        tmpl := template.New("show").Funcs(funcMap)
        tmpl, err = tmpl.ParseFiles("templates/layout.gohtml", "templates/show.gohtml")
        if err != nil {
            fmt.Println(err)
        }
        // err = tmpl.ExecuteTemplate(w, "show", data)
        err = tmpl.Execute(w, data)
        if err != nil {
            fmt.Println(err)
        }
    }
}
```

layout.gohtml:

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <title>{{block "title" .}}Default Title{{end}}</title>
</head>
<body>
    <nav>...</nav>
    <div class="container">
        {{template "content" .}}
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

show.gohtml:

```
{{define "title"}}{{.Page.Title}}{{end}}
{{define "content"}} 

    <h1>{{.Page.Title}}</h1>

    {{.Page.Content}}

{{end}}
```

Comment: So are you saying the code you posted works? If so, please show the code that doesn't. If it doesn't work, please indicate what problems you and what is the actual and expected output. Also `ExecuteTemplate()` returns an error, do check that.

Comment: This code produces a blank page and no errors... Expected output is a rendered page based on the templates... And tmpl.Execute with no name has the same blank result. I'm missing something pretty stupid I'm sure. I think it has something to do with naming the templates.

Comment: Again, `ExecuteTemplate()` and `Execute()` both return an error, do check that. The code you posted does not check that error.

Comment: If I refer to layout.gohtml it works. Except, layout is the generic component that is to be used on multiple pages. content is the page specific template. My problem is probably related to the order of nesting vs naming... i.e. my goal is to have layout:common content:specific...

Comment: Checking the err on Execute helped... If I use `err = tmpl.Execute(w, data)` I get `template: show: "show" is an incomplete or empty template` and something similar with ExecuteTemplate `template: no template "show" associated with template "show"
`. The empty template being my blank page... But why is it empty???

Comment: If I chane it to `err = tmpl.ExecuteTemplate(w, "layout.gohtml", data)`, it works. But I lose the ability to reuse the generic layout with a specific content... I'm trying to nest them in that order and then refer to the combination by "show". Am I asking too much from the Go template engine?

Comment: The template named "show" is empty because there is no template with that name in the files.  To render the complete HTML document, the application must execute the template containing the complete document.  The name of that template is "layout.gohtml".  Show the code where using layout.gohtml for different pages is a problem.

Comment: Right now this is parsing the templates on every request. If the name is "layout", then how can I parse them all at startup (ParseGlob)? Or is this a cost I have to pay to do it this way? I have not found an example of nesting done this way. Others have the specific page template pull in components like headers, footers, etc. But that seems much messier and inelegant.

Comment: ParseGlob does not make sense in this context.  With the change of the template name to "layout.gohtml", the code in the question handles the nesting scenario.  To execute the parsing code once, move the code to a context that's executed once and save the result for use in the handler.  For example, declare `var showTemplate *template.Template` as a package-level variable and initialize the variable from `main`.

Comment: Okay. I guess that makes sense. There is no magic compilation. I have to create them explicitly and store the result. That works. Thanks for your help!